# Repeat data redundant variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, promise

I have two functions that I declare the same variable twice. My code works but its not the most efficient, Can someone help me restructure the code so that I may set once and use it twice rather than setting it twice.

I was thinking something like this. but its not working

```
var promise = new Promise(function (resolve) // repeat code

    function () {
            promise. { code }
```

**Code**

As you can see bellow `var promise = new Promise(function (resolve)` is repeated in the first and second function, I feel this is not the most efficient way of writing this.

```
 var firstFunction = function () {
    var promise = new Promise(function (resolve) { 
        setTimeout(function () {
            app.post('/test.js', function (req, res) {
                console.log(req.body);
                var login = req.body.LoginEmail;
                res.send(login);
                resolve({
                    data_login_email: login
                });
            });
            console.error("First done");
        }, 2000);
    });
    return promise;
};


var secondFunction = function () {
    var promise = new Promise(function (resolve) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            nodePardot.PardotAPI({
                userKey: userkey,
                email: emailAdmin,
                password: password,
                DEBUG: false
            }, function (err, client) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error("Authentication Failed", err);
                } else {
                    var api_key = client.apiKey;
                    console.log("Authentication successful !", api_key);
                    resolve({data_api: api_key});
                }
            });
            console.error("Second done");
        }, 2000);
    });
    return promise;
};
```

Comment: Which variable are you talking about ? Can you share how `secondFunction` and `thirdFunction` are linked ?

Comment: sorry, ill update the question now

Comment: `I was thinking something like this. but its not working` - well, it's a long way from anything close to valid javascript syntax

Comment: Why don't you just return the Promise without creating a variable for it?

Comment: `I feel this is not the most efficient way of writing this` - it is though, well, close, above comment is better - i.e. `return new Promise ... lots of code ...;` - rather than `var = new Promise ... lots of code ...; return promise;`

Comment: @JaromandaX I understand its a long way from valid js, maybe i should of worded that better. if you feel its the most efficient way ok. thanks i was just asking for peer reviews or some advice.

Comment: sorry, I can't even begin to tell what that code was meant to do

Comment: @FreemanLambda that is what i was thinking, Thanks ill try this.

Comment: @FreemanLambda perfect, worked. I had tried it before but not in the correct format. thanks